# Match on Minimum Difference Between Timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (with extraneous columns removed for brevity).

actions:

```
id            user_id            action           created_at 
 1               1                open            2015-01-01 03:03:00
 2               1                closed          2015-02-03 02:13:00
 3               2                open            2015-02-04 03:23:00
```

user_logs:

```
id            user_id            source            created_at
 1               1               desktop           2015-01-01 01:59:00
 2               1               desktop           2015-01-01 02:00:00
 3               1               desktop           2015-01-01 02:00:30
 4               1               desktop           2015-01-01 02:01:00
 5               1               mobile            2015-01-01 02:02:00
 6               2               desktop           2015-01-02 01:59:00
 7               2               desktop           2015-01-03 01:59:00
 8               1               desktop           2015-01-04 01:59:00
```

And I want to join the tables both on the user ids and the smallest difference from the user_logs time to the actions time (e.g. a user would first be logged in the users_logs table prior to their action being recorded.

What is the best way to do this where it will be accurate across multiple actions for the same user?

In this example, the ideal output would be

```
user_id         action        source   
   1             open         mobile      
   1             close        desktop
   2             open         desktop
```

Comment: And the output should be?

Comment: Good point. Edited the original question to include output.

Comment: I think you need to disambiguate a little more to add clarity. What row matched what? Add a little more variation to the times and sources to make things stand out.

Comment: Why can't you store the action in the logs table? To me action is a loggable event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with an inner join, as follows:

```
SELECT 
   user_logs.user_id,
   actions.action,
   user_logs.source,
FROM user_logs

INNER JOIN actions ON user_logs.user_id = actions.user_id

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, user_logs.created_at, actions.created_at)) as minTime
    FROM user_logs
    INNER JOIN actions ON user_logs.user_id = actions.user_id
    WHERE actions.created_at > user_logs.created_at
    GROUP BY actions.id
) as minSelQ ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, user_logs.created_at, actions.created_at) = minSelQ.minTime

GROUP BY actions.id
```